# Why history listen is not updating my component's state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

TLDR:  I am building a React router app, I trying to update the state of my component through a history listener, this listener works fine I put a console.log and I can see it, but the state of my component is not changing, I can see this with the React chrome extension and my component is not updating.

`

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { styles } from './Styles';
import { url } from './App';


class Searchresults extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchResults : []
        }

    }

    async fetchResults(endpoint) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(endpoint);
            if (response.ok) {
                const rJson = await response.json();
                return rJson;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.searchUpdate();
        this.unlisten = this.props.history.listen((location, action) => {
            console.log("it works!");
            this.searchUpdate();
        })
    }

    searchUpdate = () => {
        const { location } = this.props;
        const params = new URLSearchParams(location);
        const query = params.get("search");
        const name = query.replace("?name", "s");
        const endpoint = url + "&" + name;
        this.fetchResults(endpoint).then(response => {
            return  response['Search'].map(item => {
                return { title: item['Title'], poster: item['Poster'], id: item['imdbID'] }
            })
        }).then(response => {
            this.setState({
                searchResults : response
            })
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={styles.movieList}>
                <ul>
                    {
                       !this.state.searchResults? 'Loading' : this.state.searchResults.map((item, index) => {
                            return (<li key={index}>
                                <a href={'/moviepage?id=' + item.id}>{item.title}</a><br />
                                <img src={item.poster} alt="Movie poster"
                                    style={{ width: "6rem", height: "auto" }} />
                            </li>)
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Searchresults);
```

`

I am trying to update the state with a method searchUpdate, then this method is called in componentDidMount, here works fine, then when the URL changes, the history.listen triggers and searchUpdate is fired again, and everything seems to work except the change of the state of my component.

Answer (score 0):

The first `.then` function in your searchResult function doesn't return a promise, so there is no need to use another `.then`. Just put the `setState` call in the same block:

```
this.fetchResults(endpoint).then(response => {
  const searchResults = response['Search'].map(item => {
    return { title: item['Title'], poster: item['Poster'], id: item['imdbID'] }
  });
  this.setState({searchResults})
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work